# Tensorflow Memory Issues with GPU

Tags: tensorflow

I am completely new to Tensorflow.  I have installed on RHEL7/CUDA 7.5.18/libcudnn/4.

When attempting to test the installation, I continue to get out of memory/memory allocation errors

```
cannot allocate memory for thread-local data: ABORT.
```

The install appears to work properly when I limit the processing to CPU's only (`export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""`) but, regardless of what memory limits I set, when executing with GPU's, I get memory errors.

---

I am attempting to test MINST demo model dataset get these memory issues  (models/image/mnist/convolutional.py)

I humbly realize that this is most likely some naive config issue and would greatly appreciate any assistance anyone is willing to offer.

Comment: What is the GPU you use? If you are using a nvidia GPU you can run `nvidia-smi` which will print the processes using your GPU and the GPU Memory Usage.
There might be some script using all your memory, if there is one get its PID and kill it (`kill your_PID`)

Comment: Based on tensorflow discuss thread it sounds like a general issue with CUDA. Can you get any other CUDA programs working on GPU? (ie Theano?)

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this? I'm running into similar issues, but simply allocating more memory for my job makes it go away (unsurprisingly, given the error message).